# Update Command-line Output, i.e. for Progress

Tags: php, command-line, stdout, autoflush

I'd like to be able to show a progress meter in a simple PHP script on the command line. Instead of seeing

```
Progress: 0%
Progress: 1%
etc...
```

I'd like just the number to change, and replace the previous number, much like git clone does for example `Resolving deltas: 100% (8522/8522), done.`.

While searching for this I found the [same question answered in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009258/update-command-line-output), which is perfect, but I couldn't find it in PHP. Is it possible? If not, I'll resort to C.

Thanks

**Update:** If anyone's interested in the C++ version, [it's here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221/how-to-animate-the-command-line).

Comment: usually php has finished its job before anything is sent to the browser, what's the script doing?

Comment: @Dagon he is using command-line

Comment: doh! thanks, sounds even odder then the only php command line i do is for me, its hardly suitable for a *user* interface.

Comment: Yes, it's on the command-line. It's just for simple scripts, for personal use: updating project version number, transferring files somewhere, etc.. Nothing user-facing

Comment: seems pointless to then add a progress bar. But then i'm always function over form.

Comment: @Dagon Well, I suppose there is a user - me. Sometimes it's nice to have an idea of how long something might take. And in this case, form doesn't impeed function, afaik

Comment: real men don't need pretty progress bars :-)

Comment: I just released my progressbar implementation https://github.com/Ex3v/PHP-ProgressBar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320081/clear-php-cli-output

Comment: @Adam Please consider changing best answer.

Comment: @Arek which would you suggest. Any reason?

Comment: "\r" looks simple and clean, but "\033" gives more control. Never mind.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This can be done using **ANSI Escape Sequences** -- [see here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) for a list.

In PHP, you'll use `"\033"` when it's indicated `ESC` on that page.

In your case, you could use something like this :

```
echo "Progress :      ";  // 5 characters of padding at the end
for ($i=0 ; $i<=100 ; $i++) {
    echo "\033[5D";      // Move 5 characters backward
    echo str_pad($i, 3, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . " %";    // Output is always 5 characters long
    sleep(1);           // wait for a while, so we see the animation
}
```

I simplified a bit, making sure I always have 5 extra characters, and always displaying the same amount of data, to always move backwards by the same number of chars...

But, of course, you should be able to do much more complicated, if needed ;-)

And there are many other interesting escape sequences : colors, for instance, can enhance your output quite a bit ;-)

Comment: PHP > 5.4.0 now have "\e" to write ESC

Comment: this one works in windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320081/clear-php-cli-output

Answer (score 92):

Just for the record though an old thread:
Instead of using fancy ANSI Escape sequencing to move the curser back I just move it back to the beginning of the line using "\r" instead of to the beginning of the next line "\n". Add a few spaces after your echo to overwrite anything that was there previously, like e.g. so:

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<=100 ; $i++) {
  echo "Progress: $i %   \r";
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, also on Windows! (tested)

Comment: Much easier than the solution with the most upvotes - works perfectly on OSX.

Comment: much better solution

Comment: also you can use `usleep` for big collection

Comment: you're a genius ! Works fine in Windows command line window !

Comment: This probably doesn't answer the original question better than the accepted answer, BUT it is likely more useful for what most people are looking for when they come across this question.

Comment: That's amazing！very useful！