# PHP command line - updating the output

Tags: php, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update Command-line Output, i.e. for Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265288/update-command-line-output-i-e-for-progress)

Is it possible in PHP to update the output of PHP via command line?  For instance, `echo "50%";` will add that to the output, how can I make it so that it shows `Updating files... 41%` but the % changes based on the progress of the script?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either you can simply print \r or \b, \r returns you to the beginning of the line, \b goes back a single space.

If you want to have more control than this I would suggest using the curses library.