# Echo in one line but in loop situation

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
$data  = ['a','b','c'];
$total = count($data);
for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    echo $data;
}
```

What I need is when the code is running in `cmd`, the `cmd` will output each character so that it replaces the previous character in the display, like this:

[image]

a >> then changing to show b >> then changing to show c

...only in one line.

imagine that in line 3 of cmd will show the word alternately (a -> b -> c)

I have tried with "\r" but the result is nothing in cmd.
Please can you help?

Comment: I am not doing your homework ;) But you should have a look at the `$total` variable, where is it declared? And you are echo'ing the complete `$data` array from inside your loop. Have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Comment: Sorry it is not clear how you want the output to look. Can you edit the question and show your expected output please

Comment: yeah show the word in one line alternately

Comment: On *nixy systems you can do something like: echo $data . " \r";

Comment: @JackWilko Or to work on anything `echo $data . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly `PHP_EOL` is useless nowadays though where `\n` works on all systems.

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, you misunderstand, just printing " \r"  will update the current line rather than adding a new line, i.e. for loading bars

Comment: @Xatenev Oh, does `"\n"` work on all systems. I didn't know that

Comment: @JackWilko Ahhhh! I wonder if that is what the OP is trying to say? You could be right!! Hmmmmm

Comment: @AligaMyway Can you just show the expected output instead of an explanation of the expected output? E.g. **Wanted output:** `a/b/c`

Comment: imagine that in line 3 of cmd will show the word alternately (a -> b -> c)

sorry my english is bad

Comment: So you want line 1 to output "a", line 2 to output "a -> b" and line 3 to output "a -> b -> c"?

Comment: What if OP is looking something similar to a loading feedback on which each array item is displayed as a feedback to a loading sequence? Like $data  = ['loading x','loading y','loading z']; It then makes sense when he asks to show them alternatively (just guessing BTW)

Comment: Hi @AligaMyway, I added a gif to show what I think you're trying to do. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want. Correct me if I'm wrong. It first prints `a`, then replaces it with `b`, then replaces it with `c`.

```
$data  = ['a','b','c'];
$total = count($data);
for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    echo "\033[1D";      // Move 1 character backward
    echo $data[$i];  
    sleep(1);           // wait for a while, so we see the animation
}
```

Comment: what i mean is like this

Comment: You're welcome, for more information about this, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265288/update-command-line-output-i-e-for-progress

Comment: Ah, the question makes much more sense knowing this is the answer. All the rest of us thought it was a more simple misunderstanding. Well done :-)

Comment: but i dont know that in my real code i must add echo "\r" before echo "\033[1D" to make this working

Comment: @AligaMyway not sure what you mean, why should you add `echo "\r"` to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

do like this:

```
$data = ['a','b','c'];
```

go with `foreach` like below:

```
foreach($data as $d) {
   echo "\033[1D";
    echo $d;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: cmd will show all of word,
hmmm i need that cmd will show the word in one line

Comment: llike this,
imagine that in line 3 will show the data alternately a/b/c

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you want...

```
$data = ['a','b','c'];
$total = count($data);

for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++){
    echo $data[$i] . "\n";
}
```